# How to fetch 2 or more folder with external in svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

**Context**

I'm presently using SVN [externals](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) property to fetch a folder. I'd need to fetch a second folder in the directory.

The environnement I'm working on is like this

```
  Trunk/
    Mtx/
    MtxTest/
    MtxOver/
    .../
```

**Tries**

I tried separating the list of folder with ";" but it doesn't work.

**Objectives**

I only need Mtx and MtxTest.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the dialog that appears after selecting "Externals" as the SVN property to add:

[image: TortoiseSVN Externals edit dialog]

To add an external, click the "New..." button and fill in the local path and URL for that external.  To add another one, click the "New..." button again.  Here's what it would look like with your requirements:

[image: TortoiseSVN Externals edit dialog with examples]

Comment: I was so trying to do something with and between the paths and everything! Thank you for solving another of my svn problem!!

Comment: I saw you added pictures, and I wanted to add pictures to my question to make it more clear, however is it normal it takes over 10 minutes for a 58kb jpeg?

Comment: No that's not normal. You could ask a question (to get help with uploading the image) on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).  Who knows, maybe you found a bug!

Answer (score 1):

From your link, it looks like you're using TortoiseSVN. From the exact same link, which you apparently have not actually taken the time to read:

> To add a new external, click the New... and then fill in the required information in the shown dialog.

If you're not actually using TortoiseSVN, but regular SVN, then look at the [command-line documentation for svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html):

> externals definition format...is a multiline table of subdirectories (relative to the versioned directory on which the property is set)

The link even gives an example:

```
http://svn.example.com/repos/sounds third-party/sounds
http://svn.example.com/skinproj@148 third-party/skins
http://svn.example.com/skin-maker@21 third-party/skins/toolkit
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Actually I read it but I wanted to fetch them all in a folder with the same name which didn't work when adding new ones. But seeing the answer above, I changed my way to do it. I didn't explain it afterwards, since it's mostly the way I handled my problem and it didn't affect the solution.

Comment: If you need multiple files from separate directories externaled into the same directory, then you will need to use file externals instead of directory externals. But those must be from the same repository, sadly.

Comment: thanks for the answer!! that why I decided to split them from directory and make it works that way ;)